# Margin not working only in Safari (element is at the bottom of the page)

Tags: html, css, safari

Please check the following link in the latest safari: 
http://www.grupoguion.com/

The footer is fixed at the bottom and supossed to revealed with the scrolling, so the previous section has a margin-bottom but it doesn't work, only in Safari.
Everywhere else is ok, even in I.E.
I tried to add overflow: auto in the page-wrapper, but everything gets weird in all browsers with elements dissapear and appear.
I also have read that removing height: 100% in the body and html may fix that, but that is not an option for me, because i need the images to fix the browser height.

Does anybody have another possible solution please?

Thank in advance.

Comment: please provide what you have done so far.

Comment: Hi, I have tried adding overflow: auto in the page wrapper but didn't work

Comment: You've linked to a site that's apparently already been fixed, which makes this question quite difficult to understand. Please include actual code in your question, instead of a link. (Sites like JSFiddle seem to be acceptable, but still aren't really encouraged.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a div with the size of your bottom and make it transparent.
html:

```
<div id='tr-footer'>
</div>
```

css :

```
#tr-footer{
height: ?px;
width:100%;
background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Just reading it seems ok, will try. Although is not that clean right, hahaha

Comment: It's not clean, but sometime you need to be productive :)

Comment: I have tested locally and will uploaded tomorrow.

Comment: Works ok as per your suggestion. Just in my case because i have a map there and need to be draggable, made some changes. The div can’t have the size of the bottom because block the map.
The following is what worked:

<div id='tr-footer'>
</div>

#tr-footer{
height: 1px;
width:100%;
background:transparent;
margin-top: -1px;
}

Thank you!!! Sorry but can’t vote up just yet

Comment: Why does this work? (and not the "normal" margin-bottom)

Comment: This answer is way too complicated. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925111/why-is-safari-4-mac-not-rendering-top-and-bottom-margins-in-this-nested-div

Answer (score 9):

Try making the element

```
display:inline-block
```

and Safari should respect its dimensions and margin.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is way too complicated. Consider this approach ([taken from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925111/why-is-safari-4-mac-not-rendering-top-and-bottom-margins-in-this-nested-div)):

> It's a normal weird behaviour calling margin collapse.
>   To simply avoid it add `overflow: auto;` on the [footer] container.

Your footer container could look something like this:

```
.footer-container {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: `position: sticky;` will not work, if we set `overflow: auto;` for parent.