# Cordova: Difference in layout: no margin-bottom in iOs

Tags: android, html, ios, css, cordova

I am working on a multi Os app with Cordova / Intel XDK. The user needs to be able to input something at some points. On Android all is well, but on iOs not so much. See images. Both of them are scrolled down as much as possible.

**On Android 5.1, Sony Z1**
[image: On Android 5.1, Sony Z1]

**On iOs, iPhone 4s**
[image: On iOs, iPhone 4s]

The way I was hoping to solve this it to give the `div` with the input-field a `margin-bottom: 80px;` and that works like a charm on Android. IOs just does not seem to use it. Other iPhones are used, and have the same problem.

The navigation buttons are in a `div` that uses `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`

Is there a (nice and clean) way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching this seems to be an older problem. Solved it by using `padding-bottom`, that did the trick this time, as it is possible with my layout.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431192/margin-not-working-only-in-safari-element-is-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) helped me along.